# Problems by installing Ubuntu with AMDGPU

Tags: system-installation, graphics, amdgpu

I've problems to install Ubuntu (actual 18.04) on a mainboard with AMD Ryzen 5 2400G (Raven Ridge): the system stops, dark screen and so on. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it